# Find $(x-1)(x+2)\ \equiv\ (x-2)(x+7)\ \pmod{2k+1}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

I'm a computer science student, I'm fairly new to modular arithmetic, the modulo being $2k+1$ is the thing that troubles me.
Using the  Euclidean division form of $a \equiv b \pmod n)$ rewritten as $a = kn + b$, which would be:

- $(x-1)(x+2)\ = k(2k+1)+(x-2)(x+7)$
- $x^2+x-2 = k(2k+1)+(x-2)(x+7)$,
- $x^2+x-2 = -14+k+2k^2+5x+x^2$,
- $-12+k+2k^2+4x = 0$,
- $4x = (-k-2k^2) + 12$,
- $x = -\frac{k^2}{2}-\frac{k}{4}+3$

In terms of modular arithmetic, is this solution right? Thanks!

Comment: It is not necessarily the same $ k$

Comment: Hint: $\ $  it reduces to $\,4(3-x)\equiv 0\pmod{\! m},\,$ and  $\,4\,$ is coprime to the odd $\,m,\,$ therefore $4$ is invertible so cancellable, therefore $\,3-x\equiv 0\ \ $

Comment: You are right, I got confused using the same k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you should not use the same $k$ as the multiplier for the $(2k+1)$. You should introduce some new variable, instead.

We get:
$$
(x−1)(x+2) = (x−2)(x+7) + n(2k+1)\hspace{1cm}n \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
We can expand the products, and rewrite (using basic algebra). We get:

$$
12 = 4x + n(2k+1)\hspace{1cm}n \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

Now, look at the parity (whether terms are odd or even). The left-hand side is even. The right hand side has an even term, which implies the other term must be even as well. The factor $(2k+1)$ is odd, so $n$ must be even. Let $n = 2m$.

We now get:
$$
12 = 4x + 2m(2k+1)\hspace{1cm}m \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
We can divide everything by 2:
$$
6 = 2x + m(2k+1)\hspace{1cm}m \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
We again note that everything is even except for perhaps the last term. Similar reasoning tells us that we should be able to write $m = 2l$, and divide by 2.

We get:
$$
3 = x + l(2k+1)\hspace{1cm}l \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
This means that $x \equiv 3 \mod (2k+1)$.